# IntelliJ + git + submodules -> Where do you put the .iml?

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea, git-submodules

Please note: **Not using Gradle/Maven.**

**Scenario:**

A typical Android App, requires the *Facebook SDK*, you have a few options:

1. Clone the SDK somewhere in your disk, copy the contents of `/facebook-android-sdk/facebook` (where the Android src code for the library resides) into your `/myapp/facebook` for example, import a *module* in IntelliJ, point it to this new `/myapp/facebook` path and call it a day. IntelliJ will create a facebook.iml (and will modify your project.properties and other `.idea` related files to account for this new module). You can then add this new module to your repository and treat it as just any other library.
2. Clone the SDK inside your app's directory, e.g.: `/myapp/facebook-android-sdk/*` and import a *module* in IntelliJ, point it to this new path and treat it as another git repository (you can even pull from Facebook to get new changes, albeit sometimes this may break the module).
3. Create a git submodule pointing to the Facebook SDK's github repo, import a *module* in IntelliJ pointing to the submodule, most likely correctly imported in `/myapp/facebook-android-sdk/*`.

Before moving on, let's see some particular aspects of each:

1. **PROS**: It's a fire and forget and clean approach, you can even change the SDK as you please, because you only imported the library and you have the source code. **CONS:** tedious to keep up to date. Everytime there's a new FacebookSDK update, you have to manually update your external clone, copy the SDK and/or re-add the module (and make sure stuff works!). If you have local changes, things are harder.
2. **PROS:** Easier to update than #1, but you can't really commit changes (unless you created a *fork*), because we don't have write access to the FacebookSDK. **CONS:** your `facebook.iml` and stuff will always be "*dirty*" in git, because you cannot commit it (since it's a different repo).
3. **PROS:** The cleanest approach in terms of technology, you're doing "the right thing" by using a submodule and let git point to the right repository and correctly treat it as such. **CONS:** submodules are… well delicated if not treated with care, but that asside, the same rules as #2, unless your submodule is a *fork* you can control, you can't change the FacebookSDK and commit to it, so this leaves you with the problem of the `facebook.iml` that IntelliJ creates when you add the module to your project, roaming around the submodules directory… which leads me to the question…

If you can't commit to a submodule because you have no permission (like the FacebookSDK), where (and how) can you put the module.iml (facebook.iml in this example) that IntelliJ puts inside each new module so your other users can *clone* your repository, do a `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` and not get the typical IntelliJ "Problem loading module" error. The solution to the above problem consists in each new user cloning, having to say "yes" to the "remove facebook from project" and then adding/importing the module again (dependencies, if they respect the name, are correctly saved for the other modules, so that's good).